# navigate images in Fancybox using jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins

On my website, when someone clicks on an image, it gets enlarged I would like a navigation  arrow to appear either side of the photo for people to scroll from photo to another. And photos should get scrolled when navigation arrows are clicked. I've used fancybox to display gallery.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#fancybox-left").show();
jQuery("#fancybox-right").show();
```

this will display both side arrows if you have not intiated them while initiating fancybox.